# Как создать селект меню в котором будут все участники дискорд сервера?

Tags: python, discord

Я хочу сделать так, допустим есть команда !send, которая отправляет селект меню, и мне нужно чтобы при нажатии на это меню, в его опциях выводились все участники сервера с возможностью их поиска.
Даже если больше 25 опций.
Что можно сделать? Видел, что эта реализация возможна, но сам повторить не могу

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для использования данного меню будем использовать **discord.ui.UserSelect**. Создадим для удобства класс **Select_Menu** в который и поместим **UserSelect**:

```
class Select_Menu(discord.ui.UserSelect):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(placeholder="Выберите пользователя")
    async def callback(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        return # Продолжение кода
```

Теперь отправим это в сообщении ответом на команду **!send**:

```
@client.command()
async def send(ctx):
    view = discord.ui.View()
    view.timeout = None
    view.add_item(Select_Menu()) #Помещаем наш класс
    await ctx.send("Кого выберем?", view=view) #Отправляем сообщение с данным меню
```

Подробнее о SelectMenu можно узнать на [оф. сайте](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#selectmenu).